# Does Sauce Labs support NgWebDriver?

Tags: protractor, ui-automation, saucelabs

I understand that NGWebdriver is the Java wrapper of Protractor. Protractor is supported by SauceLabs. I was wondering if you had any experience with Ngwebdriver and Sauce Labs.

Answer (score 1):

Just got an answer:

"HI!

To best of my knowledge, I don't believe we support the NGWebdriver tool.

If you like to see this type of functionality added to our platform, I would highly recommend that you submit a ticket in our Customer Idea Portal(https://saucelabs.ideas.aha.io/) requesting this feature, where our Product team directly reviews input from all of our customers as we strive to improve the Sauce Labs experience. Rest assured, our Product team definitely takes input from our customers very seriously and we try to implement as many features as we can from our customers with the limited amount resources our developers can provide in a timely basis."

Sauce Labs

Comment: I just created a new idea for this at SauceLabs.